# SSH to remote server cant connect

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, remote-server

Trying to connect to remote server via ssh but keep getting the following error:

```
zohim@Zohims-MBP ~ % ssh zchandani@lambda.lab.rigetti.com
/Users/zohim/.ssh/config: line 41: Bad configuration option: authorizedkeysfile
/Users/zohim/.ssh/config: line 82: Bad configuration option: usepam
/Users/zohim/.ssh/config: line 106: Bad configuration option: acceptenv
/Users/zohim/.ssh/config: line 112: Bad configuration option: subsystem
/Users/zohim/.ssh/config: terminating, 4 bad configuration options
zohim@Zohims-MBP ~ %
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you config file in the .ssh directory is wrong

Comment: Yep, how do I fix/reset the settings?

Comment: How to fix, hard to say without any idea how it looks like. Reset, maybe delete the file (or rename it)?